# Filter not works, needs help to understand when use child array value

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, angular8

I am trying to filter the values, what the user enter in the input. but not getting expected result. please help me to understand the wrong i do here..

here is the code :

```
    const staticData = [
  {name:'name1', firstChild:[{firstChild1:'firstChild1'}]},
  {name:'name2', firstChild:[{firstChild1:'firstChild2'}]},
  {name:'name3', firstChild:[{firstChild1:'firstChild3'}]}
]


filterIt($event) {
    this.list = staticData;
    const current = {firstChild1:$event.target.value};
    this.list = this.list.filter(o => Object.keys(current).every(k => o['firstChild'].filter(c => {
      return String(c[k]).toLowerCase().includes(String(current[k]).toLowerCase())
    }) ));
  }
```

just type 3 so, i should get only 1 value, but not getting any outupt

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6hrhje)

Comment: it works as expected... I printed the results in console; Take a look yourself... `
  filterIt($event) {
    this.list = staticData;
    const current = {firstChild1:$event.target.value};
    this.list = this.list.filter(o => 
    Object.keys(current).every(k => o['firstChild'].filter(c => {
      console.log('o:',o['firstChild'][0].firstChild1,' k:',k,' --> condition:',String(c[k]).toLowerCase().includes(String(current[k]).toLowerCase()));
      return String(c[k]).toLowerCase().includes(String(current[k]).toLowerCase());
    }) ));
  }`

Comment: @AkberIqbal - but i am not see any update on the page, can you update in demo?

Comment: which field do you wand to apply the filter on?

Comment: @IftifarTaz - i would like to apply filter on  `firstChild1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as **originally** expected:

```
filterIt($event) {
    this.list = staticData;
    const current = {firstChild1:$event.target.value};
    return this.list.filter(o => Object.keys(current).every(k => o['firstChild'].filter(c => {
      return String(c[k]).toLowerCase().includes(String(current[k]).toLowerCase())
    }).length ));
  }
```

You only need to add the `.length` and `return this.list...`.

`.length` because the `.every()` method is expecting boolean values but you are returning an array, as if an empty array could be evaluated as falsy or `false` but that is not the case. But you can use the `.length` property of that array (that returns the number of items in it) and any non-zero value equates to `true`, while `0` equates to `false` (thanks @Edric).

`return this.list...` to avoid `undefined`.

Comment: Actually, the `length` property of an array returns the number of items in the array and any non-zero or truthy values equate to `true`, while `0` or falsy values equate to `false`. This should be explained properly in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

drastically changed you `filterIt` function. Its much simpler then you are thinking.

```
filterIt($event) {
    this.list = staticData.filter(x => {
        var obj = x.firstChild.filter(y => {
            return String(y.firstChild1).toLowerCase().includes(String($event.target.value).toLowerCase());
        });
        return obj.length > 0;
    })
}
```

Here `x` is

```
{name:'name1', firstChild:[{firstChild1:'firstChild1'}]}
```

and `y` is

```
{firstChild1:'firstChild1'}
```

if search matched then `obj` has some element in it. So then checking if `obj` has `length > 0` we get the desired result.

Comment: I agree, as well I would like to hear something why my approach not works as well

Answer (score 0):

To see the effects of the filter on the page, we set a visible property inside the array which is set by the filter function - and we use ngIf in the HTML to see the effects:

relevant **HTML**:

```
<input type="text" (keyup)="filterIt($event)">
<ul>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let value of list">
    <li *ngIf='value?.visible'>
      {{value.name}}
      <div>First Child</div>
      <div *ngFor='let fchild of value.firstChild'>
        {{fchild.firstChild1}}
      </div>
    </li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

relevant **TS**:

```
const staticData = [
  { name: 'name1', firstChild: [{ firstChild1: 'firstChild1' }], visible: true },
  { name: 'name2', firstChild: [{ firstChild1: 'firstChild2' }], visible: true },
  { name: 'name3', firstChild: [{ firstChild1: 'firstChild3' }], visible: true }
];

 filterIt($event) {
    this.list = staticData;
    const current = { firstChild1: $event.target.value };
    this.list = this.list.filter(o => Object.keys(current).every(k => o['firstChild'].filter(c => {
      o.visible = String(c[k]).toLowerCase().includes(String(current[k]).toLowerCase());
      //return String(c[k]).toLowerCase().includes(String(current[k]).toLowerCase());
    })));
  }
```

working [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gvaccy)

Comment: works, but not acceptable with declaring new boolean value. the data loads from server as well i am trying to create function more generic

Comment: addition info, if I filter direct parent and return it works. when do with child it makes issues

Comment: what do you mean? i didn't get that

Comment: you should create a pipe... and put this logic inside it; that would make it reusable